# How can I make 'Kulki' run on Windows 7?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, dosbox, kulki

I would like to make [this game](http://www.grakulki.eu/windowsowe-kulki/) playable on Windows 7 (compatibility with older OS doesn't work).

I'm pretty sure it should be possible using something like DosBox, but I don't know how to configure it.

[Direct link to download this game](http://www.grakulki.eu/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/kulki.exe).

<sub>**Note:** I'm not looking for a remake so no replacement suggestions please, this has to be that game.</sub>

Comment: Just watch a youtube tutorial on how to use dosbox or virtualbox

Comment: @ioanD it's a Windows application, dosbox won't work. I'm also not sure about licencing issues with virtualbox, he would after all need something like Windows98 which I don't think is available freely.

Comment: @Deltharis, DosBOX might work: [it lists Windows 95 as supported](http://www.dosbox.com/comp_list.php?showID=3120&letter=W), and the game screenshots have a distinctly Win95 feel to them.

Comment: why not make a vm with 98 se?

Comment: Ironically, it's easier to run it from a Linux using Wine. The About dialog says "copyright 1995", but I couldn't make any of the compatibility modes work. It should be possible with Virtual PC or [Windows XP mode for Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/install-and-use-windows-xp-mode-in-windows-7), but it's much more work than one would expect.

Comment: @Mark Unless there is a hidden compatibility option - it does not work, saying that this application requires windows.

Comment: @Deltharis, well, yes, you need to install Windows 95 in DosBOX before you can run Windows 95 programs in DosBOX.

Comment: I've added the name to the question - but Is 'Kulki' the English name of the game? I can't find it anywhere :)